# Image wrapping with incomplete first row instead of last

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to solve a problem which seems to be beyond my capacities.

The thing is apparently easy. There is a collection of <img> images, to be located in a <div> box and dynamically added to it. The images are to be arranged in rows, with standard automatic line-wrapping, limited by the width of <div>, but they should be arranged in such a way that the incomplete row is not the last but always the first one, the order of images remaining the same, from the oldest to the newest. Maybe this model will explain it better than words. The example is for 4 images per row:

[1]

[1][2]

[1][2][3]

[1][2][3][4]

[1]
[2][3][4][5]

[1][2]
[3][4][5][6]

[1][2][3]
[4][5][6][7]

[1][2][3][4]
[5][6][7][8]

[1]
[2][3][4][5]
[6][7][8][9]

and so on...

So the final row should always contain as many images as the width of <div> can handle. To make the problem more difficult, the images can be of varying width, so different rows may contain different number of them. It should also work, no matter if the images are aligned to left, right or centered.

I have tried different css solutions, including first-line pseudoclass to limit the width of the first row, but it does not seem to handle the width property. Nothing works.

I will owe a lot for suggestions.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and explain the issue with each attempt

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a Javascript handler to scan the number of images in the "row"(Your class for each row), if `!=` to `4` append `<img>` element to "row". Then you would be able to class and re-class using javascript/jquery also, based off of your classes. For instance "row" could now become "full-row" and then a new `<div class="row">` can be created when a new image is added because the first existing row has 
"full-row" class.